# How to figure out the relationship between tracing spans from the headers when using W3C Trace Context

Tags: distributed-tracing

I've been reading the [W3C Trace Context](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context) spec and I can't figure out how to get child-of relationships between spans from just looking at the headers in my requests.

Assuming I understand the [processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#processing-model) correctly, the first service generates a [`traceparent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#traceparent-header), while subsequent services replace the `parentId` within the `traceparent` for downstream requests.

So Service A generates a `traceparent` and sends a request to Service B:

```
host: service-b
traceparent: 00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-00f067aa0ba902b7-01
```

Service B receives the requests and does two downstream requests to Service C and Service D each time changing the `parentId`:

```
host: service-c
traceparent: 00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b7ad6b7169203331-01
```

```
host: service-d
traceparent: 00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b9c7c989f97918e1-01
```

At the end I have three `traceparent`s in my requests

```
00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-00f067aa0ba902b7-01
00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b7ad6b7169203331-01
00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b9c7c989f97918e1-01
```

It's easy to see that they all belong to the trace `0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c`, but how do I figure out the parent child relationship between them?

My initial thought was that this is done using `tracestate`, but the spec states:

> tracestate extends traceparent with vendor-specific data represented by a set of name/value pairs. Storing information in tracestate is optional.

Answer (score 1):

As you said before, the `tracestate` field is responsible for propagate only the vendor-specific data. Moreover, the `traceparent` itself doesn't carry enough upstream-downstream relationship information. The trace context solves three problems: provide an unique identifier for individual traces, provide an agreed-upon mechanism to forward vendor-specific trace data (`tracestate`) and provide an industry standard that intermediaries, platforms, and hardware providers can support. If you want to build the upstream-downstream (or parent-child) relationship you'll need the `traceparent` of the current span scope and also the upstream's `traceparent`. Take a look at an example in c# `.NET 5`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

var upstreamActivity = new Activity("Upstream");

upstreamActivity.Start();
Console.WriteLine(upstreamActivity.OperationName);
Console.WriteLine("traceparent: {0}", upstreamActivity.Id);
Console.WriteLine("upstream traceparent: {0}", upstreamActivity.ParentId);
CallChildActivity();
upstreamActivity.Stop();

void CallChildActivity()
{
    var downstreamActivity = new Activity("Downstream Dependency");

    downstreamActivity.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(downstreamActivity.OperationName);
    Console.WriteLine("traceparent: {0}", downstreamActivity.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("upstream traceparent: {0}", downstreamActivity.ParentId);
    downstreamActivity.Stop();
}
```

the `stdout` will show something like this:

```
Upstream
traceparent: 00-192400a99d30ee459dce14655b09bc41-587841dea0e59b47-00
upstream traceparent:

Downstream Dependency
traceparent: 00-192400a99d30ee459dce14655b09bc41-d95c56215cddd74c-00
upstream traceparent: 00-192400a99d30ee459dce14655b09bc41-587841dea0e59b47-00
```

the upstream `traceparent` of the first `Activity` is empty, this means: that's the first activity of the whole trace. On the other hand, the second method has a not empty `ParentId`, so that's the identification of the upstream activity. Note that the term `ParentId` is different from the `parent-id` of the w3c spec, in `.NET 5` it represents the upstream identification. Besides that, the `parent-id` field is called `span-id` in `.NET 5`.

That's the same concept of the `stack trace`, you need both ids to build the parent-child relationship (I wrote about it in this [article](https://dev.to/luizhlelis/using-w3c-trace-context-standard-in-distributed-tracing-3743)). If you're using a framework, middleware or library different from `System.Diagnostics` and it doesn't provide the upstream `traceparent`, keep in mind that you'll need to store it in the moment it arrives at the new span scope. In other words, before the [parent-id/span-id](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/#considerations-for-span-id-field-generation) `traceparent`'s update.

Comment: Are you saying that one cannot build a trace graph without assistance from the individual components involved? Say, we have T-A and T-B (format: traceid-parentid). Only the system in between can tie A to B. To an external component (say, newrelic) which is observing, T is start of graph and everything else is a child. Do those tools use timestamp etc or I must be missing something big here given this is already adopted by many.

Comment: Hi Chethan, actually what I'm saying is: W3C traceparent doesn't define a standard for chield-parent relationships. If you want to understand how child-parent relationships between spans are conceived, my recommendation is to see other references like OpenTelemetry. The parent-id/span-id is made as 8 randomly generated bytes (note: trace-id is the identifier for the whole trace, parent-child relationships only make sense for spans).